# How to iteratively set value for every element inside an array property?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to reset all `isSelected` property inside a model to `false` (see my model below)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return [
            {
                src: 'assets/images/sample-image0.jpg',
                isInspected: false,
                isSelected: true
            },
            {
                src: 'assets/images/sample-image0.jpg',
                isInspected: true,
                isSelected: false
            }
        ];
    }
});
```

The component `side-bar`,

```
{{app/side-bar
    images=model
}}
```

Inside my component, I try to reset the selected state for each object in the model array use code below (is this the best practice to set the value?)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['side-bar'],

    actions: {
        imageClicked() {
            this._resetSelectionHighlight();
        }
    },

    _resetSelectionHighlight() {
        const images = this.get('images');

        images.forEach((img) => {
            Ember.set(img, 'isSelected', false);
        });

        console.log(this.get('images'));
    }
});
```

**My question**

What is the correct way to set the value iteratively in Ember?

Comment: How do you know it's not working, where are you checking? How are you passing the model to  your component?

Comment: I think it is working doing this way, I have updated the question.

Comment: In model return you could do some Ember.Object.create() instead of plain JS object. `return [
            Ember.Object.create({
                src: 'assets/images/sample-image0.jpg',
                isInspected: false,
                isSelected: true
            })]` and use `setEach` to set properties

Comment: @kumkanillam you can have an array of POJO's and still use `setEach`

Comment: @nem035 Thank you pointing my mistake. yes you are right `setEach` work with POJO's also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is perfectly fine.

However, Ember already defines a method [setEach](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableEnumerable.html#method_setEach) on the [MutableEnumerable](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableEnumerable.html) class that you could use.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    // ...

    _resetSelectionHighlight() {
        this.get('images').setEach('isSelected', false); // Note: images must inherit Ember.MutableEnumerable
    }
});
```

Another more generic approach that would work on any array is to create a helper to do this for you.

```
// utils/set-array-prop.js
export default function setArrayProp(arr, prop, value) {
  arr.forEach((item) => Ember.set(item, prop, value));
}
```

Then you can use it in your code like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import setArrayProp from 'my-app/utils/set-array-prop';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    // ...

    _resetSelectionHighlight() {
        setArrayProp(
          this.get('images'), // now images can be a regular array of objects
          'isSelected',
          false
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggest.

Comment: @LiXinyang no problem mate, hope it helps :)

Comment: Sorry to ask further. Why I have to use `Ember.set(img, 'isSelected', false)`? When I use `img.set('isSelected', false)` I got `set` is not defined error. (In `_resetSelectionHightlight` method, have encountered this similiar issue before)

Comment: Because your `img` items are just plain javascript objects, they don't have a `set` method. Only things that inherit from [Ember.Object](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html) have this method. You can still do `Ember.set(img, 'isSelected', false)` because `Ember.set` can set a property on any type of object.

Comment: `setEach` this is exactly what I am looking for, thank again <3